# Oracle XMLDB's XMLCAST and XMLQUERY incompatible with iBatis?

Tags: oracle, ibatis, xmltype

I've been trying to select a list of values from XMLs stored in an
XMLType column but I keep getting the errors which are listed at the
tail end of this post.

The select id is

```
getXMLFragment
```

, and the relevant subset of the
sqlmap.xml is as follows:

```
<select id="getXMLFragment" resultClass="list">
               SELECT
                   XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$CUSTOMER/CUSTOMER/DETAILS/
CUST_NAME/text()' PASSING CUSTOMER AS
                       "CUSTOMER" RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2(20))
AS customers FROM SHOP.CLIENT_INFO
</select>
```

(CUSTOMER is an XMLType column in CLIENT_INFO)

and I call the statement using

```
List<String> custNames= (List<String>)
sqlMap.queryForList("getXMLFragment");
```

I am using ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar.

Is it because iBatis does not recognise XMLDB queries and hence,
tokenizes the string wrongly?  On a sidenote, I have implemented
XMLTypeCallback.java to handle XMLType insertions successfully, and I
think it will work should I wish to retrieve the entire XML. However,
in this case, I need to extract only individual values due to
requirements. A workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

The exceptions generated are listed below:

```
--- The error occurred in sqlMap.xml.
--- The error occurred while preparing the mapped statement for
execution.
--- Check the getXMLFragment.
--- Check the SQL statement.
--- Cause: java.util.NoSuchElementException
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:
204)
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForList(MappedStatement.java:
139)
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:
567)
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:
541)
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:
118)
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:
122)
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryForList(SqlMapClientImpl.java:
98)
       at Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
       at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.sql.simple.SimpleDynamicSql.processDynamicElements(SimpleDynamicSql.java:
90)
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.sql.simple.SimpleDynamicSql.getSql(SimpleDynamicSql.java:
45)
       at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:
184)
       ... 7 more
```

Comment: Update: We just need to repeat '$' once such that the sql is "....XMLQUERY('$$CUSTOMER....."

The tokenization works fine after that and the query executes successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: We just need to repeat '$' once such that the sql is "....XMLQUERY('$$CUSTOMER....." The tokenization works fine after that and the query executes successfully.